# TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

```
def gmail_authenticate(request):
    storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()

    if credential is None or credential.invalid:
        FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                                            request.user)
        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', http = http)
        print('access_token = ', credential.access_token)
        status = True

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'status': status})
```

i'm getting

> TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable 
>              while reading the credentials

i'm getting below error.

> File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\GmailTest\google- 
>             login\gfglogin\gfgauth\views.py", line 10, in gmail_authenticate
>               credential = storage.get()
>
> TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
>             [26/Dec/2018 12:51:07] "GET /auth/ HTTP/1.1" 500 111109

i'm expecting to authenticate the gmail user.

Comment: what is `xsrfutil.generate_token`? I assume this is from some library you're using, can you link to the documentation? From the error message, it appears that this method expects an iterable to be passed as its second argument, which a Django user object is not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I can see from class documentation of `DjangoORMStorage`:

> oauth2client.Credentials retrieved from the Django ORM, associated
>                with the `model`, `key_value`->`key_name` pair used to query
>                for the model, and `property_name` identifying the
>                `CredentialsProperty` field, all of which are defined in the
>                constructor for this Storage object.

So you need to pass value of the `id` of the `DjangoORMStorage` Initiation, and it should not be an object. I think your implementation should be like this:

```
def gmail_authenticate(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Raise or Return Not authenticated response

    storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user.id, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()

    # Rest of the Code
```